Clarification on Self-Attention vs. Spatial and Channel Attention, and Their Implementations in MATLAB
I’m researching attention mechanisms in deep learning, and I have a couple of questions regarding their functionalities and implementations:
Functional Differences: Does self-attention fulfill the same role as spatial attention and channel attention, or do they address different aspects of feature importance? How do they compare in terms of what they aim to achieve?
Implementations in MATLAB: I know that self-attention layers have been implemented in MATLAB since R2023a (selfAttentionLayer). Are there built-in functions for implementing spatial attention and channel attention layers in MATLAB as well? If not, could you suggest ways to implement them?
I appreciate your help and insights on these topics!
Thank you!
I implement the self-attention layer
